# integer Input() variable to assign to a function

Tags: python

I have a list of variables that call functions. These variables are numbered from 1 to 5 and each of the integers should call a function to gather the required information. Them method of selecting the variable is by a console input i.e. input("Select a Number")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxpd7.png)

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question and these are difficult to answer concisely, which makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. If you really don't know where to start and need guidance or support consider mentoring and coaching services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: `answer = input()`, `if answer == "1": view_15_cities()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to execute a function upon getting a number, then you can try **pseudo** **switch** clause :-

```
def switch(i):
    py_switch = {
            1: lambda: function1(),
            2: lambda: function2(),
            3: lambda: function3(),
            4: lambda: function4(),
            5: lambda: function5(),
        }
    function = py_switch.get(i)
    function()

choice = int(input("Enter your choice = "))

switch(choice)
```

This is sort of equivalent of switch clause (found in languages like C++, Java etc), takes in a single input and provides output according to the input value.

It is a little harder to implement then the normal `if-else` ladder found in most program's.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a way to associate numbers with functions, the most straightforward way I can think to do that is with a list.  This is exactly what a list does...associates objects with numeric indexes (positions in the list).  An advantage of this over other methods is that your code does not have to change as you add and remove functions from the list, because it can base its logic on the length of the list.

Here is an example that calls a particular function given a number as input:

```
def function1():
    print("I am function 1")

def function2():
    print("I am function 2")

def function3():
    print("I am function 3")

def function4():
    print("I am function 4")

def function5():
    print("I am function 5")

functions = [function1, function2, function3, function4, function5]

f = input("Enter a number between 1 and {} > ".format(len(functions)))
try:
    i = int(f)
    if i < 1 or i > len(functions):
        print("There's no function with number " + f)
    else:
        functions[i-1]()
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

You can do the same thing more compactly with lambda (anonymous) functions.  Since you're referencing the functions by number, they don't need names:

```
functions = [
    lambda: print("I am function 1"),
    lambda: print("I am function 2"),
    lambda: print("I am function 3"),
    lambda: print("I am function 4"),
    lambda: print("I am function 5")
]

f = input("Enter a number between 1 and {} > ".format(len(functions)))
try:
    i = int(f)
    if i < 1 or i > len(functions):
        print("There's no function with number " + f)
    else:
        functions[i-1]()
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Given that lambdas limit you to a single expression, and I assume you'll want more complex functions, I'm guessing that the first version is what you'd want to go with.

Comment: Your description of curly brackets and `lambda` return values is completely wrong. Your code works, but only because the curly brackets are creating a `set` literal in the `lambda` function. That is a *very* sketchy way to run multiple lines of code, and it doesn't actually let you run any *statements* (like assignments), only extra expressions (like function calls). The return value from the lambda will be a set containing the unique values from all the expressions.

Comment: Oops.  I kinda knew that, but obviously not well enough.  Am I getting mixed up with Java maybe?  Thanks...I'll change the code.